# Dynamically add an option with data attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple select inputs, with class - `seltohide`.
Need to add an option to a visible one:

```
ajax...
success: function(data) {
    var name = 'Blue Sky';
    console.log(data); // result: 5*lorema*loremb
    var id = data.split('*')[0];
    var uname = data.split('*')[1];
    var pass = data.split('*')[2];
    var obj = $('.seltohide:visible');

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = id;
    option.text = name;
    ...
    obj.add(option);
}
```

Final result should be like this:

```
<option value = 5 data-uname = 'lorema' data-pass='loremb'>BLUE SKY</option>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access `data` attributes using the `dataset` property of the element.

```
option.dataset.uname = uname;
option.dataset.pass = pass;
```

Or since you're using jQuery, you can create the object with the data attributes in one call:

```
var option = $("<option>", {
    value: id,
    text: name,
    data: {
        uname: uname,
        pass: pass
    }
});
obj.append(option);
```